# How to properly index table

Tags: mysql

We use to index our tables basing on `where` statement. It works fine during our `MSSQL` days, but now we are using `MySQL` and things are differenct. Sub-query has terrible performance.
 Consider this table :

```
# 250K records per day
create table t_101(
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_date` datetime not null,
  `memo_1` nvarchar(255) not null,
  `memo_2` nvarchar(255) not null,
  `product_id` bigint not null,
  #many more columns

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  key `index.t_101.101`(`transaction_date`, `product_id`, `memo_1`),
  key `index.t_101.102`(`transaction_date`, `product_id`, `memo_2`)
)ENGINE=MyIsam;
```

A temporary table where I store condition values :

```
# 150 records
create temporary table `temporary.user.accessibleProducts`
(
    product_id bigint not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)Engine=MyIsam;
```

And this is the original query :

```
select

COUNT(a.id) as rowCount_la1,
COUNT(DISTINCT a.product_id) as productCount

from t_101 a

where a.transaction_date = '2017-05-01'
  and a.product_id in(select xa.product_id from `temporary.user.accessibleProducts` xa)
  and a.memo_1 <> '';
```

it takes 7 seconds to be executed, while this query :

```
select

COUNT(a.id) as rowCount_la1,
COUNT(DISTINCT a.product_id) as productCount

from t_101 a
inner join `temporary.user.accessibleProducts` b on b.product_id = a.product_id

where a.transaction_date = '2017-05-01' 
  and a.memo_1 <> '';
```

takes 0.063 seconds to execute.. Even though `0.063 seconds` is acceptable, I'm worrying about index. With the given above, how do I index `t_101` properly? 

We are using MySQL 5.5.42.

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to let MySQL show you what the query plan looks like, i.e. which indices are used and how.

Comment: Upgrading to MySQL 5.6+ should fix the subquery variant (by converting it internally to a join - just like you did). Other than that you can try a composite index on `(transaction_date, product_id)`, but I'm not sure it will help - you will have to test it.